# push data to at the end of each value in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have some array like this

```css
Array(
    [0] => {"puroriid":"3902598","purorid":"3901727","iid":"3927478"}
    [1] => {"puroriid":"3902599","purorid":"3901727","iid":"3927486"}
    [2] => {"puroriid":"3902600","purorid":"3901727","iid":"3927486"}
)
```

Here i want to add some data to at the end of each looping so data will look as follow.

```css
Array(
    [0] => {"puroriid":"3902598","purorid":"3901727","iid":"3927478","variation_name"=>"tiles" ,"hsn" =>"42424"}
    [1] => {"puroriid":"3902599","purorid":"3901727","iid":"3927486","variation_name"=>"wood","hsn" =>"63636"}
    [2] => {"puroriid":"3902600","purorid":"3901727","iid":"3927486","variation_name"=>"granite","hsn" =>"66656"}
)
```

I tried array push method but its created another index , instead of adding new data to last

below is my code.

```html
 $items = array();
        $variations = array();
        if ($purchaseOrderDetails->getOrderItems())
        {
            foreach ($purchaseOrderDetails->getOrderItems() as $key => $item)
            {
                $items[] = strval($item);

                  $variations[] = strval(new InventorySetVariation($item->getIsvid()));
            }
        }

        Utility::ajaxResponseTrue("", array("po" => strval($purchaseOrderDetails), "items" => $items, "variations" => $variations));
```

Here I want to merge item and variations as one array .

how can I achieve it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is the example may help you to achieve similar goals of yours

```
<?php
$items = array(
    0 => '{"puroriid":"3902598","purorid":"3901727","iid":"3927478"}',
    1 => '{"puroriid":"3902599","purorid":"3901727","iid":"3927486"}',
    2 => '{"puroriid":"3902600","purorid":"3901727","iid":"3927486"}'
); //Your Items

$itmesNew = [];
foreach($items as $val)
{
    $newItem = json_decode($val,true);
    $newItem['variation_name'] = 'test';    //New Items Append            
    $newItem['hsn'] = '123';                //New Items Append
    $itmesNew[] = json_encode($newItem);    //Add as json
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($itmesNew);
?>
```

Output

```
Array
    (
        [0] => {"puroriid":"3902598","purorid":"3901727","iid":"3927478","variation_name":"test","hsn":"123"}
        [1] => {"puroriid":"3902599","purorid":"3901727","iid":"3927486","variation_name":"test","hsn":"123"}
        [2] => {"puroriid":"3902600","purorid":"3901727","iid":"3927486","variation_name":"test","hsn":"123"}
    )
```